# Implement Sliding Window Algo in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sliding-window

I want to implement Sliding Window Algorithm.
The goal is to show all my window(s).
But i just got 1 window only. 
Here's my code:

```
clc;clear all;`   
image = imread('tabTes.png');
imageWidth = size(image, 2);
imageHeight = size(image, 1);
windowWidth = 100;
windowHeight = 100;
for j = 1:imageHeight - imageHeight + 1
    for i = 1:imageWidth - imageWidth + 1
        SlideWindow = image(j:j + windowHeight - 1, i:i + windowWidth - 1, :);
     end
end
figure
imshow(SlideWindow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
clc;clear all;`   
image = imread('tabTes.png');
imageWidth = size(image, 2);
imageHeight = size(image, 1);
windowWidth = 100;
windowHeight = 100;
for j = 1:imageHeight - windowHeight + 1
    for i = 1:imageWidth - windowWidth + 1
        SlideWindow = image(j:j + windowHeight - 1, i:i + windowWidth - 1, :);
         figure
         imshow(SlideWindow);
     end
end
```

Be careful, though. This will generate a lot of figures.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But the output it just the same as mine :(

Comment: sorry did not capture your index variables. see my edits in a minute

Comment: Thanks bro it works! 
And there's another problem that i want to solve.
For the next hours i will post it in here. 
So glad if you want to help me (again) :D